# What is the simplest way to test ActionResult for "yellow screen of death"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

I have an action like this:

```
 public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var model = someFactory.CreateModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

What is the simplest way to test it on  "yellow screen of deth" appearance?

Ofсourse I'll mock `some Factory` logic.

I just want to test `ViewResult` on some stupid syntax runtime errors.

**Update:** In controller logic is no exceptions, but some time I could get runtime exception while ExcecuteResult method excecution. In other words I what to test View rendring process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the view results, here is a blog post how to do it with Razor:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html

If you are using WebForms views you will have to use a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that error handling is done with `HandleErrorAttribute`, in case of an exception it will use `HandleErrorInfo` as a model and `Error` view (if otherwise not specified). So all you need to do is test which view the controller  rendered.

For this type of testing I suggest you use [TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper&referringTitle=Documentation).